# Changing state in a given thread form another process

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I wish to control the value in a given thread from another process. The following doesn't work since `dproxy[i]` is a value rather a proxy. How should I be doing this?

```
import multiprocessing
import time
import threading

def g(d):
    while d:
        print(d)
        time.sleep(1)

def f(dproxy):
    for i in ("1","2"):
        t = threading.Thread(target=g, args=(dproxy[i],))
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()
    time.sleep(10)

manager = multiprocessing.Manager()

dproxy = manager.dict()
dproxy["1"] = "A"
dproxy["2"] = "B"

p = multiprocessing.Process(target=f, args=(dproxy,))
p.daemon = True
p.start()

time.sleep(2)
dproxy["1"] = "C"
time.sleep(2)
```

**UPDATE**

Second attempt that also doesn't work.

```
import multiprocessing
import time
import threading

def g(d):
    while d:
        print(d)
        time.sleep(1)

def f(dproxy):
    print(type(dproxy["1"]))
    for i in ("1","2"):
        t = threading.Thread(target=g, args=(dproxy[i],))
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()

    time.sleep(10)

manager = multiprocessing.Manager()

dproxy = manager.dict()
dproxy["1"] = manager.Value("s","A")
dproxy["2"] = manager.Value("s","B")

p = multiprocessing.Process(target=f, args=(dproxy,))
p.daemon = True
p.start()

time.sleep(2)
dproxy["1"].set("C")
time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: sorry, what do want to happen here? the only easy way to exchange data between two processes is to use shared memory (if you want state only the events may help you). Also why do you insist on mixing threading with multiprocessing (are you aware of GIL)?

Comment: @user3012759 There's nothing wrong with a process having its own threads. I'm not using events I'm using a Shared Memory Manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you've got

`t = threading.Thread(target=g, args=(dproxy[i],))`

which will evaluate when creating the thread, so argument to your thread will be just your immutable string and that falls off from the manager

if you want to change it later you want to pass the your `dproxy` not an element of it.

EDIT: Ok, so after looking into it bit more, it seems you are hitting a possible [bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue6766) that prevents nested proxies to work correctly as it seems that as soon as you nest a proxy it gets 'de-proxied' and you end up with plain value.

In your second example however you can just change from `manager.dict()` to plain `dict()` as you don't use it anyway it, but this will break if you actually try to modify the `dict` itself but will work for the `values` as they will arrive in your threads as proxy objects and will pick up the fact that they get modified using `.set`

Comment: @dproxy I dont wish to pass a dictionary to each thread function since they should only be interested in a single value. I tried adding Value proxies to my dictionary proxy and then later I reset one of these Values but again the value wasn't updated in the corresponding thread.

Comment: can you show code for that maybe? because for it to work you need to pass a proxy to your thread as once you pass value directly you lose the proxy part and it just falls off of the manager

Comment: Added in my question.

Comment: @Baz edited with some more details, hopefully useful